# Erro org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException ao executar um relatório jasper

Tags: ireport, jasper

Ao receber esse erro, verifique como está a propriedade language do seu relatório.
Se estiver como Groovy, altere para Java que resolverá o erro.

[image: Groovy]

[image: Java]

Att.